# Using Multiple Database in Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using Azure Redis Cache, not able to find proper document on advantages of using multiple database in Azure Redis Cache.

I am using ConnectionMultiplexer object in StackExchange.Redis DLL to connect Redis (Premium Tier).

What are the benefits of storing different keys in different Redis cache DB in the same Redis instance? or is it better to use Clustering in Redis for some extra billing amount?

```
cache0 = Connection.GetDatabase(0);
        await cache.StringSetAsync(cacheKey0, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data0));

cache1 = Connection.GetDatabase(1);
        await cache.StringSetAsync(cacheKey1, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data1));
```

Comment: I can't speak to performance, but I can say that we store info that needs to be flushed upon redeploy in one database, and stuff that needs to survive a republish in another database. It just makes it easier to use the flushdb command without having to iterate over all keys to remove them. Note that flushdb is still O(N) time.